# How To Create A Console With JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, console, jtextarea, jtextpane

I tried making a console in a JTextArea that took a string called 'text' and everytime the user did something that I wanted logged in the console, 'text' would be assigned different text (that had to include all the text from before). Then I would just go and add that string to the JTextArea with: *console.setText(text);*

I read around and found that if you use JTextPane instead of JTextArea, you can change the colors of the text (which would be nice to do), so I tried implementing that into my code, but it was WAY to difficult passing around that one string to different methods and having to constantly change all the others (damn strings). It doesn't help that the JTextArea can only display one thing with the *.setText()*.

**What would be the simplest option to create a working console with JTextPane? Are there any other libraries I can add that might make this easier?**

(I also read around about some code to take "System.out.println()" statements and sent that to their console view instead of the IDE's console. I'm guessing that makes adding text easier right?)

Comment: I think you better have a look at [Using Text Components](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) and try and gain a better understand of what the role the `Document` plays.  `JTextArea` also has a nice `append` method, which you can replicate in `JTextPane` using the `Document`

Comment: *"(I also read around about some code to take "System.out.println()" statements and sent that to their console view instead of the IDE's console. I'm guessing that makes adding text easier right?)"* - No, or not really, you'd still need to "append" the new content to the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also read around about some code to take "System.out.println()" statements and sent that to their console view

For example you can check out the [Message Console](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/) which can support different color for System.out and System.err messages.